# Using local facts (`ansible_local`) when they may not exist

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible for an automated deployment.

The installation of a certain software package I need is a long, non-standard and boring operation. I'd like to run the corresponding tasks only if necessary, that is if it wasn't already executed before.

My plan consists in having the last step of such installation to create a local fact:

```
- name: Flag installed
  block:
    - file:
        path: /etc/ansible/facts.d
        state: directory
    - copy:
        src: mypackage.fact
        dest: /etc/ansbile/facts.d/mypackage.fact
```

The `mypackage.fact` file is this:

```
[general]
installed=yes
```

At this point I'd like to use such local fact as conditional, so I can avoid running the boring procedure twice:

```
- include: install_boring
  when: not(ansible_local.mypackage.general.installed | bool)
```

Obviously this fails because `ansible_local` is not defined. I know the `default` filter exists, but it feels just unconfortable to do a multi-level default for each of `ansible_local`, `mypackage`, `general` and `installed`.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably a dirty hack, but checking if the file exists seems to do the job

```
- name: Check custom mypackage facts exists
  command: grep -q installed /etc/ansible/facts.d/mypackage.fact
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: mypackage_fact_exists

- name: Prepare MyPackage
  when: (mypackage_fact_exists | failed) or not(ansible_local.mypackage.general.installed | bool)
  block:

    ...LOTS OF STUFF HERE...

    - name: Flag installed
      block:
        - file:
            path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/
            state: directory
        - copy:
            src: mypackage.fact
            dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/mypackage.fact
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reload ansible_local with setup module:

```
- name: "reload ansible_local"
  setup:
    filter: "ansible_local"
```

as it says:

> Path used for local ansible facts (*.fact) - files in this dir will be run (if executable) and their results be added to ansible_local facts if a file is not executable it is read.

[setup – Gathers facts about remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but still coming up on top for "*ansible checking if local fact does not exist*".

The most elegant answer I've found is to check for `X is not defined`. You still need to create a custom fact (which means you need to [create a custom facts directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts)) once, but subsequent executions can read all facts in a way that is consistent with Ansible's semantics.

```
- name: test play
  hosts: hosts
  
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory for ansible custom facts
      ansible.builtin.file:
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
        path: /etc/ansible/facts.d

    - name: execute the command
      command: echo 'this command will only run once, ever'
      register: cmd_executed
      notify: Finished executing command
      when: ansible_local.cmd_executed is not defined
      
    - name: print message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ cmd_executed }}"

  handlers:
    - name: Finished executing command
      copy:
        content: '{{ cmd_executed }}'
        dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/cmd_executed.fact
```

More details in [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables).